# Getting "mount.nfs: mount system call failed" on mounting HDFS

Tags: linux, hdfs, mount

I am trying to mount the HDFS file system as per the content in the URL http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html

But at the final mount statement, I am getting the `mount.nfs: mount system call failed`

I got that output on executing the below command:

```
mount -t nfs -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock,noacl <HDFS server name>:/ <existing local directory>
```

I am running the hadoop in a Pseudo Distributed mode.

Comment: This seems like a question which is better suited over on "serverfault.com". More linux gurus over there ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use root to mount nfs at client, for example, you need to add following configuration in core-site.xml under $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/

```
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
```